# Bootstrap Tooltips Don't Work

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 project that includes three buttons with tooltips embedded in a div called "A":

```
<div class="A">
    <span></span>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdfsdf" id="aButton">A</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdljkfl" id="bButton">B</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdljkfl" id="cButton">C</button>
</div>
```

On document.ready, I call this jQuery function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.A .btn').tooltip();
});
```

No tooltips are displayed.  I check my BundleConfig to ensure that bootstrap.js is included:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js",
"~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
"~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
"~/Scripts/bootstrap-3.2.0-dist/js/bootstrap.js"));
```

Yeah, it's there.  Why are my tooltips not showing up when I hover my cursor over the buttons?

**EDIT**: The console now yields the following error: TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function.  Also, the document.ready function is located at the very bottom of my View.  There are no other document.ready functions located anywhere in the View, or its layout.  The bundle is called at the *top* of my View, like so:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr", "~/bundles/jquery", "~/bundles/flot")
```

Comment: any console errors????

Comment: It works in Bootsnipp: http://bootsnipp.com/user/snippets/7Xxdr  Maybe an issue with your browser?  Make sure the site is not in Compatibility Mode if you are using IE.  Also, use F12 tools to make sure Bootstrap is actually loading.  Try it in Firefox/Chrome and see if there is a difference.

Comment: @Kartikeya - there are no console errors, and I know that the jQuery code is being called.

Comment: @L_7337 - this doesn't work in Firefox nor Google Chrome; F12 shows that bootstrap.js is loading correctly

Comment: You don't show it above, but you are loading the Bootstrap CSS too, aren't you?  There is nothing wrong with the code.  Its either the browser, or some conflict with javascript/jquery.

Comment: @L_7337 - bootstrap css is loading correctly.  Now the console *is* showing an error, weirdly, that it wasn't showing before: TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function.

Comment: Is this the document.ready of the View or of the _Layout page.  There 'may' be a conflict there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58274/discussion-between-alex-and-l-7337).

Comment: The sample you provide simply works. In the case you get console errors you either have a typo in your BundleConfig's `~/Scripts/...` include, or you're executing the `$(document).ready....` before the bundles (bootstrap) are loaded. If you don't get any console errors, you're probably not loading bootstrap's css.

Comment: @Moriarty, I don't see any typos in the BundleConfig (I updated my question to provide more details about it), and the `$(document).ready` bit is being called inside of the View, at the very bottom.  It's the only time I call `$(document).ready` in the entire project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, what you're trying to do works. In order to prove this try the following:

Setup your **_Layout.cshtml**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    <!--
        Note: Register script bundles here...
        Just for the sake of getting it to work, I'm using CDN here
    -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Important: load page-specific scripts *after* the includes above -->
    @RenderSection("Footer", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Then, in the view (Home.cshtml):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="A">
        <span></span>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdfsdf" id="aButton">A</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdljkfl" id="bButton">B</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Default tooltip" title="sdljkfl" id="cButton">C</button>
    </div>
</div>

@section Footer {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.A .btn').tooltip();
        });
    </script>
}
```

This is copy/paste ready and will work. But there are some things to take into consideration here:

- Load `$(document).ready...` after the loading of the scripts; you'll see the custom section "Footer" I've provided in the sample
- Try debugging it with a CDN first to see if you can get it working; then you can focus on the BundleConfig
- Last tip is to make sure there's enough 'visual room' to display the tooltips (in your case above the buttons)

Comment: I marked this as my answer, although my issue is still unresolved. My particular issue might be stemming from using a Bootswatch CSS theme - no idea.  Thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Make sure your JQuery libraries are up to date.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. There were two issues I had to deal with to get Bootstrap 3.2 Tooltips to work.

## 1. Make sure you load jQuery.js before you load bootstrap.js.

## 2. Check your containers and the z-index.

It seems that tooltip defaults to a z-index of 0 from within the element. It was hiding behind my main container. Forcing the tooltip into a higher z-index (I.E. z-index:1;) worked for me.

Add this to your CSS and increase the z-index until it becomes visible.

```css
div[role='tooltip'] {
    position:relative;
    z-index:1;
}
```

This solution worked for me instantly, albeit I'm using a different framework (Zend/Magento 1.7.0.2).

[edit] The position and z-index was specific to my situation (the default value was being reset from 1060 to 0). I do not recommend doing the same thing unless the code is executing properly and you are still unable to see the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to include:

```html
<script src="~/Scripts/umd/popper.js"></script>
```

or

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
```

if you prefer to use a CDN